# How to click a javascript button via Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to pull some quotes on a website. To get the quote you have to click the Javascript button below:

[image]

Below is my python code to click the button:

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("http://generatorland.com/glgenerator.aspx?id=86")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@href='JavaScript:void(0);']").click()
```

However, when I run the code to test the button press, it throws an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='JavaScript:void(0);']"}
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=110.0.1587.46)
```

Why can't it find the button, even when I specify the href sample for the XPATH to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move a step deeper and use the *`<img>`* tag.

---

### Solution

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a > img[alt='Confucius']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a/img[@alt='Confucius']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This took me 3 hours until you answered a question. Thank you, unsung hero!